# sql query for posts with specific tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have posts, tags, post_tags tables.

Now I want to get all posts that have (a, b, d) tags,

how do I achive that and not only getting all posts with one/two/all tags?

```
tables:

posts:
id, title

tags:
id, title

post_tags:
post_id, tag_id
```

my simple idea was this query:

```
select *
from post_tags pt
join posts ps on pt.post_id=ps.id
where pt.tag_id in (MY_DESIRED_TAGS)
```

this surely doesn't work as i get posts with only one of the tags and not all of them.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `posts`, `tags`, `post_tags` where `posts`.`ID` = `post_tags`.`post_id` and `tags`.`ID` = `post_tags`.`tag_id`;

Comment: The `in` is like using an `OR` you want to use `AND`. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: So (a, b, d) are tags->title or tags->id

Comment: Your question __ISN'T CLEAR__

Comment: the: a, b, d are tag ids of course, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.*
from posts p join
     post_tags pt
     on pt.post_id = p.id
where pt.tag_id in (MY_DESIRED_TAGS)
group by p.post_id
having count(*) = <# desired tags>;
```

The key is counting the number of tags that match.  If you have three tags, then the `having` clause would be:

```
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: look like a nice idea! I'll try that tomorrow! tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts ps 
WHERE ps.id IN (
   SELECT pt.post_id 
   FROM post_tags pt
   WHERE pt.tag_id IN ([MY_DESIRED_TAGS])
   GROUP BY pt.post_id
   HAVING COUNT(1) = [THE_NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_TAGS]
)
;
```

The subquery finds the number of tags (out of the ones supplied) for every post and gives the post id values as a result set. The outer query then finds the posts with those id values. It can be done as a JOIN as other answers have indicated, but the way I have suggested *might* be faster since the server will not have to handle data irrelevant to the actual group operation.